# What does the Doctor suddenly remember when Missy reveals her real identity and why was he spooked?

Tags: doctor-who

When Missy reveals who she really is in Series 8 Episode 11 *Dark Water*, she says "Couldn't very well keep calling myself the Master, now could I?" After  he recognises her, the Doctor looks spooked; he looks like he's seen a ghost. What memories of his encounters with the Master was he thinking of when he realised it was his old arch-nemesis? Why was he spooked?

Comment: Are you new to the series and starting at that season?

Comment: No I have seen all season 1-9 and all 13 doctors

Comment: Then you'll know [The Master](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Master) is his recurring arch-enemy he previously believed [was dead or at least sent back to the Last Great Time War](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_End_of_Time_(TV_story)).

Comment: Was that why he was spooked or was it something else

Comment: With all the comments, the question is still not clear. Do you mean if he remembers something he'd forgotten (like the title states)? Or, which of the Master's atrocities creeped him out the most (as the body of the question seems to ask)?

Comment: I meant was he shocked that he's back to wreak havoc and he remembered his past  encounters with the master and the laugh and four knocks

Answer (score 2):

The main reason The Doctor becomes spooked is because he couldn't believe that it really was The Master regenerated as a female.

During the ending of The End of Time when The Timelords attempted to come back he seemingly sacrificed himself by blasting Rassilon with the energy he had within him.  The Doctor knew that The Master couldn't survive what was happening to him and therefore most likely assumed that he had died or was trapped with Rassilon and the other Timelords in The Last Great Time War, which was time-locked.

http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_End_of_Time_(TV_story)

> As the Master counts the drums one last time, his blasts occupy Rassilon long enough for a bright flash of light to send the all of them — the Time Lords, Rassilon, Gallifrey, and the Master, back into the last day of the Last Great Time War.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of unpleasant experiences that the Doctor has had with the Master, any one of which would probably be enough to worry the Doctor:

- The Master once got himself elected PM of Britain, then took over the world and shrunk the Doctor.
- The Master once turned everyone on Earth into a replica of himself, creating the amusingly-named Master Race.
- The Master has possessed or controlled numerous individuals, including some close to the Doctor.
- The Master once tried to frame the Doctor for assassination.

...and many more.

Comment: I think it was all of the masters incarnations in the past and all of his encounters with him in the past  the Harold Saxon laugh and the four knocks which made him spooked what about that